# How to decode InputValue of ethereum using java web3j

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp, web3j, java

**I'm trying to decode the inputValue of an transaction using web3j without using any contract abi and wrapper class,Im loading the contract using its contract address ,is there any way/inbuilt function to decode inputValue **

```
    List<TransactionHistory> history = new ArrayList<TransactionHistory>();
    BigInteger block = web3.ethBlockNumber().send().getBlockNumber();
    int block_no = block.intValue();
    // Class obj[]= new Class[array_length]

    TransactionHistory ts[] = new TransactionHistory[block_no];

    while (block_no >= 0) {

        List<EthBlock.TransactionResult> txs = web3
                .ethGetBlockByNumber(DefaultBlockParameter.valueOf(BigInteger.valueOf(block_no)), true).send()
                .getBlock().getTransactions();
        txs.forEach(tx -> {
            int i = 0;
            EthBlock.TransactionObject transaction = (EthBlock.TransactionObject) tx.get();
            if ((transaction.getFrom().toLowerCase()).equals(address.toLowerCase())) {
                // System.out.println("***************GETTING INSDIE OF IF LOOP***********");
                ts[i] = new TransactionHistory();
                ts[i].setFrom(transaction.getFrom());
                ts[i].setTo(transaction.getTo());
                ts[i].setBlockNumber("" + transaction.getBlockNumber());
                ts[i].setGasPrice("" + transaction.getGasPrice());
                ts[i].setNonce("" + transaction.getNonce());
                history.add(ts[i]);
                i++;
            }

            /*
             * if (transaction.getHash().equals(
             * "0x72d108f9e1f08dd23df9d31cf8a0e954644c8944f89430247c7ecaa3b3cec3ad")) {
             * System.out.println("TransactionAdapter to address: " + transaction.getTo());
             * System.out.println("Input: " + transaction.getInput()); }
             */

            BigInteger val = BigInteger.valueOf(transaction.getInput().hashCode());
            String txHash = transaction.getBlockHash();
            // transaction.setInput(val.toString());
            System.out.println("*******" + "\nGET INPUT " + transaction.getInput() + "\nBlockNumber: "
                    + transaction.getBlockNumber() + "\n From: " + transaction.getFrom() + "\n To:"
                    + transaction.getTo() + "\n Nonce: " + transaction.getNonce() + "\n BlockHash:"
                    + transaction.getBlockHash() + "\n GasPrice:" + transaction.getGasPrice());



            // transaction.getTransactionIndex();
            BigInteger transactionIndex1 = transaction.getTransactionIndex();
            String size="0xfdacd5760000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001";
            System.out.println(transaction.getValue());//getting zero value

            System.out.println(transaction.getTo());//not getting address of receiver
            // to fetch sentTo and transaction value->
            String inputData =transaction.getInput();//trying to decode this function

            if(inputData.length()>size.length()) {
                Erc20.getIputDataDecoder(inputData);
            }else {
                    System.out.println("INPUT DATA IS INVALID HENCE ,Sent Value:"+transaction.getValue()+"  Sent to contract "+transaction.getTo()+"\nBlockNumber:"+transaction.getBlockNumber());
            }
        });
        block_no--;
```

**` here is an function where im trying to decode inputValue **

```
private static void getIputDataDecoder(String inputData) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String method = inputData.substring(0,10);
System.out.println(method);
String to = inputData.substring(10,74);
String value1 = inputData.substring(74);
Method refMethod = null;
try {
    refMethod = TypeDecoder.class.getDeclaredMethod("decode",String.class,int.class,Class.class);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
refMethod.setAccessible(true);
Address address1 = null;
try {
    address1 = (Address)refMethod.invoke(null,to,0,Address.class);
} catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("SENT TO: "+address1.toString());
Uint256 amount = null;
try {
    amount = (Uint256) refMethod.invoke(null,value1,0,Uint256.class);

if(amount!=null) {
System.out.println("Value Sent: "+amount.getValue());
}
}catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

```
 List<EthBlock.TransactionResult> txs = web3
                .ethGetBlockByNumber(DefaultBlockParameter.valueOf(BigInteger.valueOf(block_no)), true).send()
                .getBlock().getTransactions();
        txs.forEach(tx -> {
            int i = 0;
            EthBlock.TransactionObject transaction = (EthBlock.TransactionObject) tx.get();
```

transaction.getValue();//having problem in these two functions,getting zero value
transaction.getTo();//this one too,getting contract address instead of receivers address
System.out.println(transaction.getValue());
System.out.println(transaction.getTo());
}

Comment: Yes, should be pretty easy.

Comment: @goodvibration  how can i do it ?

Comment: How can I answer that when I don't see your code in front of me???

Comment: @goodvibration here's an code snippet ,where im trying to fetch transaction details

Comment: Wait, are you looking to **encode** an input value before sending the transaction? I don't quite understand the meaning of "decoding an input" (i.e., either you encode an input or you decode an output).

Comment: @goodvibration im fetching data from all the availabe blocks from my ganache,and then fetching each and every transaction

Comment: @goodvibration i need receivers address and the value which is sent

Comment: @goodvibration my getIputDataDecoder(String) function giving me details about receivers address and amount which is being sent,but according this logic when input data changes contract to contract it fails

Comment: It's too much code. Can you please post just the part that you're having a problem with?

Comment: @goodvibration can u tell me that how can i fetch details about transaction receivers address and the amount which is sent to him ?

Comment: @goodvibration have uploaded the function where im getting a problem

Answer (score 0):

```
    ERC20 javaToken = ERC20.load(contractAddress, web3, creds, new DefaultGasProvider());
    System.out.println("ALL HISTORY OF TT");
    javaToken.transferEventFlowable(DefaultBlockParameterName.EARLIEST, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST)
     .subscribe(event
     -> System.out.println("from: " + event._from + ", to: " + event._to + ", value: " + event._value));
```

**This function helped me to reach my goal**